# Mysql check if string contains numbers

Tags: mysql, sql, string, where-clause

I want to count the number of different magnets that are in my table.

They´re defined by a string of around 20 elements, of which I´m interested in the first five.

All of them have the same pattern:

```
mgn##
```

the word mgn followed by two numbers. I have to specify that the fourth and fifth element are integers, as some of the rows have letters after mgn.

I´ve tried different queries so far, just guessing in the air.

```
mysql> SELECT DISTINCT(SUBSTRING(magnet, 1, 5)) FROM magcom WHERE magnet LIKE '%mgn\d\d%';
mysql> SELECT DISTINCT(SUBSTRING(magnet, 1, 5)) FROM magcom WHERE magnet LIKE '%mgn##%';
```

These gives the message `empty set`.

Any help would be apprciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `RLIKE`:

```
WHERE magnet RLIKE 'mgn[0-9]{2}'
```

If you want the match at the beginning of the string only:

```
WHERE magnet RLIKE '^mgn[0-9]{2}'
```

Comment: Thx. That worked. However, would it be possible to do the same, but taking account that some of them may have just one number? It would be something like '^mgn[0-9]{2}'  AND '^mgn[0-9]{1}' I suppose, but then SUBSTRING is misplaced.